# How to Store digits

Tags: python

Hello i am making a MPH converter to KPH
the only thing I need help with is how you store digits.
Basically I want to be able to write in a random digit for example 170 mph and then it will store the digit and then later convert it kph. I have tried searching it up but I can't find any thing that helps me

edit: I am very sorry wasting everybody's time I had no idea that the documents existed so again I'm am very sorry I'm just a beginner
hope you understand

```
print("Type in the Mph speed")
input()
```

Comment: This is the most basic usage of `input()`. Did you read the [documentation?](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#input) What do you find is unclear? `input()` returns a string. You need to convert it to an integer or a float to use it as a numeric quantity.

Comment: You need to store your value in a variable x = input(“Type in the Mph speed”)

Comment: Duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20449427/how-can-i-read-inputs-as-numbers Please don't ask a new question on Stack Overflow when a search would suffice. [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/261593/843953)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I read inputs as numbers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20449427/how-can-i-read-inputs-as-numbers)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can store things in variables - the `input` function returns what the user typed in as a string, so you have to use an `int` to convert it into a number:

```
print("Type in the Mph speed")
speed = int(input())
```

You can also simplify this by putting the string in the `input` function:

```
speed = int(input("Type in the Mph speed: ")) # This will print on the same line as the user input, hence the colon and space to make it more readable
```

This is a very basic question, though, so I would suggest looking at a python tutorial/the docs.

Comment: You simplify it further by `input("Type in the Mph speed")`

Comment: I'll add that, sure @Flair.

Comment: _"This is a very basic question, though, so I would suggest looking at a python tutorial/the docs."_ It also means there's very likely a duplicate already on Stack Overflow, so it's better to just mark as a duplicate instead of adding an answer.

Comment: I guess you are right... I will do that next time then @PranavHosangadi

Answer (score -1):

This is done by input function
a = Input ("enter your number:  ")
What this line does is that.. It displays " Enter your number: "  On the output screen and request you to give any input and store that input to the variable 'a' here.
But in input function.. By default.. Always a character type is going stored. Here in the above code.. If you type 120 in the console.. Always a character type variable is gonna store in 'a' variable. So you have to make it an integer type. You can do that by.. Using

a = int(input ("enter your number "))

This line is gonna take your input and convert it into a integer type from a character type. And it is gonna store in 'a' variable.